# Guardar la conexión en app.config de manera encriptada

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

¿Es posible guardar una cadena de conexión de app.config sin guardar el password, o de alguna manera encriptarlo, usando entity framework?
Sin usar windows auntentication, osea con usuario y password.

Ejemplo de conexión:

```
<add name="conexionEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Integration.Models.conexion.csdl|res://*/Integration.Models.conexion.ssdl|res://*/Integration.Models.conexion.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(local);initial catalog=db_ejemplo;user id=sa;password=123456789;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

password=123456789 <-- este dato es el que no me gustaría que estuviera expuesto en el app.config

Comment: Revisa [estos](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Encrypt-and-Decrypt-Connection-String-in-AppConfig-file.aspx) [enlaces](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33347667/4092887).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Puedes [encriptar partes del `Web.config`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dtkwfdky.aspx#Anchor_2) tal y como se muestra en el link para evitar que se pueda acceder a esa información.

**EDIT**

Ejemplo del proceso de cifrado:

1. Editar el `Web.config` con un editor de texto. Asegurarse de que `<system.web>` contiene los elementos secundarios: `<connectionStrings>` y `<machineKey>`. Un ejemplo podría ser:

```html
<configuration>
   <connectionStrings>
      <add name="SqlServices" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=Northwind;" />
   </connectionStrings>
   <system.web>
     <machineKey validationKey="D61B3C89CB33A2F1422FF158AFF7320E8DB8CB5CDA1742572A487D94018787EF42682B202B746511891C1BAF47F8D25C07F6C39A104696DB51F17C529AD3CABE"
       decryptionKey="FBF50941F22D6A3B229EA593F24C41203DA6837F1122EF17" />
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```

2. Con el símbolo de sistema ir a: `cd \WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v2.0.*`
3. Una vez allí, ejecutar el siguiente comando: `aspnet_regiis -pe "connectionStrings" -app "/MyApplication"`. Este comando cifra la sección de `<connectionStrings>` de la aplicación `MyApplication`.
4. Repetir el paso anterior para el elemento `<machineKey>`: `aspnet_regiis -pe "system.web/machineKey" -app "/MyApplication"`

Ahora el contenido del Web.config ya está cifrado.

**EXTRA**

Acceso a los datos cifrados:

Aunque ASP.NET descifra automáticamente el contenido del archivo `Web.config` cuando lo procesa y que no se necesita ningún paso adicional para leer el archivo, puede ser interesante saber como ver la información descifrada. Para acceder a ella, se puede hacer mediante estas líneas de código.

```
  Configuration config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(Request.ApplicationPath);
  MachineKeySection key = 
    (MachineKeySection)config.GetSection("system.web/machineKey");
```

Comment: El ejemplo se ve muy bien, había visto ejemplo mas extensos, ese esta perfecto, pero igual ¿me podrías explicar como usarlo?

Comment: El mejor ejemplo es seguir paso a paso el link, yo no podría explicarlo de mejor forma. Mediante el '<machineKey>' y la línea de comandos se tiene que generar un nuevo Webconfig que esconde el contenido de connectionStrings. @CristinaCarrascoAngulo