# Ocultar Información Confidencial o Privada en un Proyecto

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Hace poco, comenze a trabajar con la API de [OpenWeatherMap](https://openweathermap.org/api) dentro de soluciones en Visual Studio.

Para evitar publicar las claves de acceso, hay que mantenerlas en un archivo/ubicacion que no sea incluido por error en una commit de GitHub.

Teniendo en cuenta de que estoy usando C#:

1. ¿Cual es el lugar correcto para guardar informacion sensible dentro de una solucion o proyecto?
2. ¿Como puedo evitar tener que ingresar esta informacion o claves constantemente durante las compilaciones?

Comment: Desgraciadamente tu pregunta se basa en opiniones. ademas das poca informacion sobre que tipo de claves estas tratando de guardar.

Comment: Agregue un poco mas de informacion a la pregunta. En teoria, esta lo "bueno" y lo "correcto". Busco hacer lo correcto durante el desarrollo para evitar cualquier tipo de problemas a futuro.

Comment: El tema es que no hay algo correcto. Hay algo que funciona y algo que no. y las cosas que funcionan pueden ser varias.. sigue siendo basada en opiniones... Ademas algo no me cierra. si estas en un entorno corporativo, esas claves deberian ir dentro de github, para que todos las usen...

Comment: No estoy en un entorno corporativo, creo programas y modificaciones que van a repos publicos en GitHub bajo MIT. El publicar las claves de la API permitiria el abuso por parte de terceros.

Comment: Lemon, básicamente estás preguntando como hacer que git no haga traking  de ciertos archivos? Conoces el uso del archivo `.gitignore`?

Comment: Se como usar los ignores de git, pero como mencione en la segunda pregunta quiero evitar tener que insertar esa informacion cada vez que trabajo (en un nuevo dispositivo, por ejemplo).

Answer (score 0):

Deberías quitar las cadenas de la API de tu código y, para tenerla siempre disponible, sácala a un archivo de configuración `app.config` o `web.config` según sea tu caso. [Consulta aquí cómo trabajar con archivos de configuración](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms254494(v=vs.110).aspx).
Como ejemplo te dejo mi caso:

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="nombreDeClave" value="valorDeClave" />
    ...
  </appSettings>
  ...
  <!-- O bien -->
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="TuApp.Properties.Settings.nombreDeClave" connectionString="valorDeClave"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Una vez que tengas dicho archivo con una sección en donde almacenes la clave de la API, debes consultarlo en el compilado:

```
using System.Configuration;
namespace ...
{
    class ...
    {
        private string _cadenaApi;
        void LeerCadenaApi()
        {
            _cadenaApi = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["nombreDeClave"].ToString();
            // O bien
            _cadenaApi = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TuApp.Properties.Settings.nombreDeClave"].ConnectionString;
        }
    }
}
```

Una vez que tengas esta configuración, tienes dos caminos para evitar compartir dicha clave:

1. Si acabas de crear el archivo de configuración o antes de hacer el primer commit, en los archivos modificados buscar el `App.config` o `Web.config` según tu caso, darle clic derecho y seleccionar "Omitir este elemento local" u "Omitir esta extensión".
2. [Encripta la sección](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/38289/guardar-la-conexi%C3%B3n-en-app-config-de-manera-encriptada) de *esa* configuración y mándala así al repositorio. De esta manera podrás compartir toda la configuración de tu aplicación pero sin mostrar el contenido privado.